# Symfony 2: Check name of host and redirect

Tags: php, symfony

My website listens to two domains: one.example.com and two.another-example.com.

When a user visits my contact page via "http://one.example.com/contact", I would like to automatically redirect the user to "http://two.another-example.com/contact". The content of the page is the same, just the URL will be a different one.

In my controller in my contactAction I use the following code to check the host:

```
/**
* @Route("/contact")
*/
public function contactAction(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getHost() == 'one.example.com') {
           // redirect
        }
...
```

The redirect does not work. I am 99% sure it is because of the `getHost()`-check, which is why I included only that part of my code.

Does anyone see a solution?

Comment: what is `echo $request->getHost()` ?

Comment: The `if($request->getHost() == 'one.example.com') {}` is OK to me. Check the redirection part.

Comment: Are you sure that the route is well configured and runs code inside `contactAction()` method? Have you tried to print `$request->getHost()` output and check if it's the same of `one.example.com`? And finally, maybe you have to check the redirection part as written by @AlFonce. Write us the redirection part if you want more help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use other ways like  in javascript

```
<script>
var a = window.location.href ;

if(a =="your_first_domain_link") {
    window.location.href = "your_2nd_domain_link"
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps